# What causes the dallied hiding of the load more button in this Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have been working on an app with Angular 2+.

I am currently working on loading more items at the click of a "Load more" button.

In `users.component.ts` I have:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../../models/empModel';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.css'],
})
export class UsersComponent {
  public itemsNumber: number = 4;

  public more: Boolean = true;

  public empsArray: Employee[] = [
    { empno: 10256, ename: 'Scott', job: 'Manager', deptno: 10 },
    { empno: 10257, ename: 'Smith', job: 'Lead', deptno: 20 },
    { empno: 10258, ename: 'Sandy', job: 'Programmer', deptno: 30 },
    { empno: 10259, ename: 'Sam', job: 'Tester', deptno: 40 },
    { empno: 10260, ename: 'Jane', job: 'Manager', deptno: 10 },
    { empno: 10261, ename: 'Jim', job: 'Lead', deptno: 20 },
    { empno: 10262, ename: 'Prter', job: 'Programmer', deptno: 30 },
    { empno: 10263, ename: 'Andrew', job: 'Tester', deptno: 40 },
    { empno: 10264, ename: 'Andy', job: 'Manager', deptno: 10 },
    { empno: 10265, ename: 'Gina', job: 'Lead', deptno: 20 },
    { empno: 10266, ename: 'John', job: 'Programmer', deptno: 30 },
    { empno: 10267, ename: 'Alice', job: 'Tester', deptno: 40 },
  ];

  public loadMore() {
    if (this.itemsNumber >= this.empsArray.length) {
      this.more = false;
    } else {
      this.itemsNumber += this.itemsNumber;
      this.more = true;
    }
  }
}
```

In `users.component.html` I have:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Employee Number</th>
      <th>Employee Name</th>
      <th>Employee Job</th>
      <th>Employee Deptno</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of empsArray | slice: 0:itemsNumber">
      <td>{{ item.empno }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.ename }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.job }}</td>
      <td>{{ item.deptno }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="more" class="my-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <button (click)="loadMore()" class="btn btn-primary">Load more</button>
</div>
```

#### The problem

I want the div above - containing the button - to hide when the last item in the `empsArray` loads.

Instead, it only disappears only of I click the button once more, *after* the last item has loaded.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you add the markup for the `button` you mentioned into your question? I assume it's something like `<button *ngIf={{more}}>` or similar, but I think we need to see what's there to get a full picture.

Comment: I think you posted incomplete html, there's no div with button

Comment: Are you binding to `more` to hide the div which contains the button? It's tough to say without seeing that markup but this might be due to not using Observables.

Comment: No worries, just as I expected :) I think my answer is doing what you need!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to edit your `loadMore` function like this. Do the check and update `more` after you update the `itemsNumber` variable.

```
  public loadMore() {
    if (this.itemsNumber < this.empsArray.length) {
      this.itemsNumber += this.itemsNumber;
    }
    if (this.itemsNumber >= this.empsArray.length) {
      this.more = false;
    }
  }
```

Edit: Messed up my comparison! Should have been `>=`, not `===`

Comment: Not working. I have added a links to a Stackblitz.

Comment: Your stackblitz has my function backwards

Comment: Ooops, i was looking at wrong part of stackblitz, sorry! Still looking :)

Comment: Had a mistake in my function: should work now!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-modal-bootstrap-ybfpkb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fusers%2Fusers.component.ts working stackblitz